# C# How to make a prompt similar to SET /P in CMD?

Tags: c#

How to make a prompt similar to SET /P in CMD?

I am trying to do this:

```
(PATH VARIABLE): <user input here>
```

I am using it for a CMD shell emulator I am making.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking; are you asking how to ask for user input, store it in a named variable or create a system environment variable?

Comment: Do you know about Console.ReadLine? (If you are making a command line app, that is)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yes. My problem is it's in 2 separate lines. I want it to be in 1 line together.

Comment: So create a method that prints the message you supplied and waits for the answer to return

Comment: @HansKeﬆing What I want it to do is return the current path, then make the user input something. It will be stored as a variable called "command"

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("My Command : ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input.ToUpper() == @"SET /P")
        Console.WriteLine("command correct : " + input);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("command wrong : " + input);
}
```